# How does QMake process .prl files of static libraries?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I need to pass certain #define from library to main application. As far as I understand, it can be achieved with .prl files.
I've created simple subdirs project to test it:

This is main project file:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    app \
    lib

app.depends = lib
```

This is library project file:

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = lib
TEMPLATE = lib
# Added create_prl option
CONFIG += staticlib create_prl
# This is the define I want to pass to main application
PRL_EXPORT_DEFINES += TEST_PRL_DEFINE

SOURCES += lib.cpp

HEADERS += lib.h
```

This is main application file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = app
# Added link_prl option
CONFIG += console link_prl
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../lib/release/ -llib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../lib/debug/ -llib
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../lib/ -llib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/release/liblib.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/debug/liblib.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/release/lib.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/debug/lib.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/liblib.a
```

However, when I build the project (in Qt Creator, if that matters), no #define seems to be passed to main application except the standard ones:

```
cd lib\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\qmake.exe C:\Qt\projects\test_prl\lib\lib.pro -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ) && C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/lib'
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/lib'
# Here you can see that TEST_PRL_DEFINE is added to defines of library project
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DTEST_PRL_DEFINE -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\..\test_prl\lib" -I"." -I"..\..\..\5.4\mingw491_32\include" -I"..\..\..\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"..\..\..\5.4\mingw491_32\mkspecs\win32-g++"  -o debug\lib.o ..\..\test_prl\lib\lib.cpp
ar -ru debug\liblib.a debug/lib.o 
ar: creating debug\liblib.a
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/lib'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/lib'
cd app\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\qmake.exe C:\Qt\projects\test_prl\app\app.pro -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -o Makefile ) && C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/app'
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/app'
# Here no TEST_PRL_DEFINE is added to #defines of main application project
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=c++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\..\test_prl\app" -I"." -I"..\..\test_prl\lib" -I"..\..\..\5.4\mingw491_32\include" -I"..\..\..\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"..\..\..\5.4\mingw491_32\mkspecs\win32-g++"  -o debug\main.o ..\..\test_prl\app\main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\app.exe debug/main.o  -LC:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/app/../lib/debug/ -llib -LC:/Qt/5.4/mingw491_32/lib -lQt5Cored 
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/app'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/projects/build-test_prl-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug/app'
```

However, `lib.prl` file is created during build process and placed next to `liblib.a`.

How should I use create_prl/link_prl options?

Answer (score -5):

better write clean makefiles on your own - the whole qmake stuff is far beyond any hope.

right now, I have to find why it silenty adds totally broken linker options like -L/usr/lib ... they're appearing in .prl files, but no idea where it comes from. smells like they never ever read the pkg-config manpage ...

Comment: Your answer is outside the scope of the problem since the question author wants to use `qmake`.